# How can I work with greenplum data using spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, greenplum

I have a project in witch I read data from hadoop and make some calculations. Everything is done using spark. It's very important to not save data anywhere when I don't need that. That's why spark plans works so good for me. But now I have to somehow do the same operations on greenplum data without any big changes in my project.
Is moving data from greenplum to hadoop and then make calculations with it the best option? If yes, what connector do you prefer to use? If no, what do you think will work better?
Thank you for your help.

I tried to use a jdbc connector, but it works so slow because of working with master node only. I want reading to be carried out by several executors like when I read data from hadoop.

Comment: Have you tried following the https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html, specifically setting `numPartitions`, `partitionColumn`, lower and upper bounds?

Comment: Do you already have data in Greenplum? If not, connecting to Spark ThriftServer over JDBC could be an option. Otherwise, Presto can be faster than Spark, but it really depends on your dataset